# What was the first Belarusian novel?

Tags: history-of-literature, belarusian-language

While reading the [Wikipedia article about Belarusian literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_literature) and the articles about individual authors who were active before World War II, it struck me that most authors were poets, with some of them also producing drama or translations. The main article doesn't mention novels until [after World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_literature#Post-war_period) and the earliest mention of a novel in the articles about individual authors is one by [Maksim Bahdanovič](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maksim_Bahdanovi%C4%8D):

> In 1907 [Nasha Niva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasha_Niva) came out with Bahdanovič's first published work — the novel *Muzyka*.

Was *Muzyka* the first novel written and published in Belarusian or were there any earlier examples in the genre? If there were earlier examples, what are the title and the author of the first Belarusian novel?

Comment: The question may sound basic, but the information about Belarusian literature is so scant that one probably needs to consult sources in Belarusian or Russian to answer the question.

Comment: Would you consider [Jan Barszczewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Barszczewski) a Belarusian?

Comment: @user58697 The decisive factor for this question is not whether a specific *author* can be considered Belarusian but whether he wrote a novel in Belarusian.

Comment: He did. _Драўляны дзядок і мадам Інсекта_ is written in Belarusian.